# How do I install Battlefield Bad Company 2?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

My DVD of Bad company 2 arrived from Amazon today. I have never installed a game from disk before. Will there be a huge download during installation (I am low on internet data). Also, I wish to play online. Do I need some additional software?

Comment: Why don't you try it, and see what happens?

Comment: On the box, it is written that the serial key can be used only once for online play. I am afraid that I might lose the key if I mess up during installation.

Comment: Also, I will recharge my data pack, if a huge download is required.

Comment: You can either use the CD installer, or install the game through Origin (the key can be activated there). Either way you'll need to download updates and Origin will install the latest update with the game and generally be a less-pain-in-the-neck than the standalone installer.

Answer (score -2):

You only have to download updates and anti-cheat software, the main content of the game itself is already on the disk.
Probably "Origin" should be installed as well.
This is in general for physical media games (Exception of MGSV: TPP that the physical media only came with the installer of Steam LOL).